# What is the slowest fixed-wing airplane?

Tags: aviation-history, airspeed, fixed-wing

It's easy to find information about the fastest airplanes, in different categories (e.g. [X-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_X-15), [SR-71](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird), the [Concorde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorde) etc), but what is the slowest one? Which powered, manned airplane is capable of sustained level flight at lowest velocity?

Comment: A hovering helicopter is an aircraft! An airship is an aircraft. Are you asking only about **fixed-wing** powered aircraft?

Comment: All VTOL will tie for the win.

Comment: I wonder if any of [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQJKW5vfvog) would take the prize?

Comment: Nobody has mentioned the military jets such as the Harrier which can hover (or even fly backwards) using vectored thrust. I guess this is "cheating" in the context of this question, or possibly not sufficiently sustained before it consumes a full load of fuel.

Comment: @nigel222: It needs to be an airplane (sustained by lift from wings, not by thrust) else a helicopter would also be relevant, and maybe Elon Musk rockets.

Comment: Note that an autogyro is kept aloft by lift from its wings, which (unlike the rotor blades of a helicopter) are not powered; a separate propeller provides forward thrust to keep the aircraft moving forward,which causes air to flow past the wings. And an autogyro can fly very slow. But since the wings autorotate, the autogyro is not considered a fixed wing aircraft; it's a footnote to this question rather than an answer.

Comment: I propose that to solve this puzzle we have a race and see who comes in last, with the owner of that plane receiving a(n) hefty prize... and each person will fly a plane that isn't their own.

Comment: They aren't going to be winners in this competition, but two curiosities that would make a fine addition here would be the ["Flying Pancakes" (Vought V-173/XF-5U)](http://www.eugeneleeslover.com/VIDEOS/Flying_pancake.html), which had extremely unusual wing geometry and very low stall speeds by design. The XF-5U, which had been built, taxi-tested but not _really_ flown, would have had stall speeds ~20 kts.

Comment: Hmm... This question says "at lowest velocity." Did you perhaps mean "lowest airspeed?" It's quite possible to sustain flight with negative forward velocity (relative to the ground) in a strong headwind in a fixed-wing aircraft.

Comment: I've had people tell me they landed a C42 backwards, so less than 0kts forward speed :)

Answer (score 95):

The [Gossamer Albatross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacCready_Gossamer_Albatross) is a [human-powered plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-powered_aircraft) with a top speed of 29 km/h (18mph).

[image: Gossamer Albatross in flight, with two bicycles following it on the ground]

It was used to cross the [English Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Channel) and seems to meet the criteria of the question.

Comment: Well... http://newatlas.com/mow-cycle-human-powered-riding-mower/14491/

Comment: This aircraft is as much powered as... the two bicycles below it ;-)

Comment: It's very *Kiki's delivery service*  :)

Comment: Is there any info about the stall or minimum speed?  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39327/whats-the-slowest-airplane#comment103345_39373 suggests it can fly at 7mph, but is there anything more definitive?

Comment: The 7 mph from that answer was for the Gossamer Condor, the predecessor of the Albatross.

Answer (score 61):

The [Antonov AN-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-2) has no stall speed quoted in the operating manual and can fly under full control at about 30 mph. Thus if the headwind is sufficiently large the aircraft will move backwards with respect to the ground.

[image]

Comment: DHC-2 Beaver is similar. Normal landing speed is about 45mph, meaning it can be operated significantly slower than that.

Comment: I've flown one (as a passenger) on a sightseeing flight. Nice machine, albeit not the most comfortable one.

Comment: @el.pescado me too - just about.  It was the first time I had ever been in an aircraft without large tubofans, and if my wife was not with me to relate the tale to my friends after,,  I would have bailed out of the thing before the takeoff run:)   The rising whine of the inertia-wheel starter brought on a sort of panic attack...

Comment: @MartinJames it had been my first filght in my life, and it had been years before commercial flights become affordable for average Eastern Europe citizen. That means, until relative recently, my impression of flight was based on that An-2 flight;)

Comment: Does that mean a 30mph wind will lift the airplane off the ground?

Comment: @Chloe, that is why they strap-down light aircraft if heavy winds are expected:
http://www.pilotweb.aero/polopoly_fs/1.4881486!/image/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_630/image.jpg

Comment: I saw one of these at Cable airport in California in the 90ies. It was huge, and yellow. The best part is that you can fly it with nothing more than a private pilot license and a tailwheel endorsement.

Comment: [Here you can see it happen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTbm5ZzZQy8); not sure if it actually goes backwards, but comes very close.

Comment: `if the headwind is sufficiently large the aircraft will move backwards with respect to the ground` technically, this is true of all aircraft.

Answer (score 47):

[The Harrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrier_Jump_Jet), [Yak-38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakovlev_Yak-38), [Yak-141](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakovlev_Yak-141), [XV-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_XV-15), and [V-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Boeing_V-22_Osprey) are all fixed wing aircraft. All can hover in mid air, controlled.
So they are in controlled flight at 0 velocity.

At least the Harrier can even be in controlled flight flying backwards, so with negative velocity. The others may as well, I don't know.

Comment: I should have expected this;) How about "ordinary", non-VTOL aircraft?

Comment: Another trick answer would be - small model aircraft.  In fact, do those things fly slowly??  Or does it not scale like that?

Comment: @Fattie the requirement for the airplane to be manned may exclude all but the largest model aircraft, not even considering whether manning them would be safe, legal, feasible, ...

Comment: Oh sorry - I missed that requirement.

Comment: You could also use the trick of requiring a very small "man" (see Jessica Dubroff).

Comment: From what I understand, the fuel consumption per minute on those jets is much higher when they are hovering than when they are cruising.  If one were to rank planes by the airspeed that maximizes time aloft per unit of energy, I wonder which plane would rank lowest?

Comment: @supercat probably something like a 787 or A350

Comment: Nah, the velocity is never negative unless it is in relation to a fixed point, such as the destination....

Comment: Don't forget the F-35B bro!

Comment: @JustACoder that one didn't exist at the time this answer was written :)

Comment: Well it actually did exist 4 years before this question was written:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW28Mb1YvwY

Answer (score 21):

now, if you're looking at modern, more commonly used transportation, powered paragliding would probably take the cake.

[image]
<sup><sup>CC BY 3.0, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=13110495</sup></sup>

> Powered paragliders usually fly between 15 and 50 mph (25 and 72 km/h) at altitudes from 'foot-dragging on the water' up to 24,000+ ft (5400 m)

<sup><sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powered_paragliding</sup></sup>

The beginners equipment are often the slowest, and with proper skill, and the right weather, can have a stall speed of **zero**. Whilst being lifted by a thermal, the only thing that will push the glider forward is the natural tilt. naturally, on a still day, the slowest of equipment will stall at below **10mph**.

<sup>Disclaimer: this is not an airplane, but it is a fixed wing vehicle, made to primarily move forward to generate lift, akin to most airplanes.</sup>

Comment: Further comments regarding the appropriateness of this answer to the question [can be found in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/62863/discussion-on-answer-by-tuskiomi-what-is-the-slowest-fixed-wing-airplane).

Comment: "The beginners equipment are often the slowest, and with proper skill, and the right weather, can have a stall speed of zero" is patently wrong. It can have *ground* speed of zero, but that's true of any wing with sufficiently strong headwinds. But it will never have an air speed of zero (or even infinitesimal) and keep generating lift, which is the only thing referenced when discussing stall speed.

Comment: @mathrick actually, doing special maneuvers can allow you to paraglide backwards, even on days with no wind! depending on what OP means by slowest, this may be allowed!

Comment: When you're flying backwards, that's because the wing is either stalled, or sinking. I dunno how paragliders accomplish that, but in parachutes (specifically, BASE canopies), sustained straight-down / backwards flight is accomplished by having bottom-skin vents which allow the wings to pressurise and effectively change the relative wind direction. In non-vented accuracy canopies, straight down (but not backwards) flight is possible in deep brakes, but even then the *airspeed* is not zero, it's positive and a high angle of attack. Even if it's sinking, the parachute is still not stationary.

Comment: @mathrick Well, here's the thing. From an airspeed prospective, the *only* thing that paragliders do is sink. I think it may be going over your head how this works.

Comment: Sure, and they do it at a non-zero speed, any time the wing is flying.

Comment: @mathrick I think that if we're using the same definition of flying (flight) as the answer with the VTOLs, I don't think that we even have to be moving to be flying. Maybe they're using flight incorrectly. I don't think so.

Answer (score 18):

If you are including historical aircraft, the [Wright Flyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Flyer) averaged 10 fps (approx 6.8 mph or 11 kph) over it's first 120 foot flight in 1903.

Reference: https://airandspace.si.edu/exhibitions/wright-brothers/online/fly/1903/triumph.cfm

Comment: Wind did a lot to make this slow speed possible.

Comment: What is "kph" for a Unit? Or did you mean `km/h`?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Yes, kph and km/h are the same thing: kilometers per hour.

Comment: Did anyone else see "10 fps" and think "10 frames per second"?

Comment: Tony - no, nobody thought that  :)

Comment: Peter: I saw no info about wind direction, didn't know if it was a headwind or a crosswind. Since the flight was northbound, I would have assumed crosswind. Per the linked site, subsequent flights had a higher average speed. Tony: funny. :)  Highlights the importance of context.

Comment: @tony, yeah, frame rates were crappy back then

Comment: When I saw "10 fps", I was thinking "ferrets pedaling slowly".

Comment: @GalacticCowboy The thing with kph is that it's not actually used all that much in countries that use kilometers. In fact, it mostly seems to be used by north Americans who try to to convert mph into metric.

Comment: @AndrejaKo It's also widely used in the UK; it's a legitimate abbreviation in English.

Answer (score 15):

[Gossamer Condor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacCready_Gossamer_Condor), the first [human powered airplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-powered_aircraft) capable of basic maneuvered flight.  When it finally won the [Kremer prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kremer_prize) for a 1 mile figure 8 course it did that course in 7 minutes and 22 seconds.

The later [Gossamer Albatross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacCready_Gossamer_Albatross) that crossed the [English Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Channel) had to be faster.

This assumes that the question criteria was AIRSPEED (not groundspeed) for a fixed-wing, man-carrying aircraft that could take off and land under its own power and maneuver both into and out of the wind (figure 8 maneuver).

Comment: Wow. 7mph! That's slower than most paragliders

Answer (score 14):

Building it just for very slow speed does not look practical (if you really need this, use helicopter). Some old planes may be slower, but they do not use the newest technologies and may not be built for slow flight anyway. Some patrol, agricultural planes may benefit from slow flying, but we need something more extreme.

I expect such aircraft to be some specific machine that has a huge wing and low weight for other reasons, and should be recently built to benefit from latest technologies.

[Solar impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Impulse) looks like a good candidate. It has take-off speed of 35 km/h (22 mph) only. [Looks like](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39472/what-would-be-the-stall-speed-of-solar-impulse) its minimal speed is about 20.67 mph only. Its large wing holds the solar batteries. It has a wingspan larger than [Boeing 747](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747) and the weight close to [Cessna 172](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_172)!

[image: Solar Impulse from Wikipedia Commons]

(picture from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_Impulse-IMG_8424-white.jpg)).

Comment: Agricultural planes can fly very slow in general

Comment: Even if not designed to fly slow, some airplane simply *has* to be the slowest one.

Comment: Some aircraft were designed with good low speed performance in mind, either because helicopters didn't exist at the time or because they aren't practical for the job the aircraft was designed to perform. The Tiger Moth comes to mind, and indeed some models of crop duster aircraft. The DHC-2 Beaver was designed with very slow stall speed to allow it to land in remote areas with hardly any flat space to use as a runway. Examples are legion.

Comment: @el.pescado The math pedant in me wants to add "assuming there are only finitely many airplanes". ;-)

Comment: @Charles actually, there might be infinitely many airplanes, [it's only neccessary that every totally ordered subset has lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) ;-)

Comment: @el.pescado If the speed of airplane number `x` (where `x` is any natural number) is given by the formula `30 + (1/x)`, which airplane has the lowest speed?

Comment: @ChrisW how many mathematicians does it take to fly an aeroplane? ;-)

Comment: @ChrisW BTW that set of airplaines doesn't satisfy Zorn lemma (linked by me) preconditions.

Comment: This is probably actually the answer.

Comment: The [Gossamer Albatross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacCready_Gossamer_Albatross) had a ***top speed*** of 18mph, and an average speed of 7.8 mph.

Answer (score 14):

The **Ruppert Archaeoptrix Electro** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruppert_Archaeopteryx), [official website](https://www.ruppert-composite.ch/en/)) apparently has a stall speed of **30 km/h (19 mph / 16 kn)**, and I think that makes it a candidate for the current "slowest" fixed wing aircraft.

It is a relatively new glider that can be foot launched, but there are also wheeled and motorless configurations, and it can also be launched by towing.

[image]

For the motorized version:

Comment: *Which powered, manned airplane is capable of sustained level flight at lowest velocity?* While your answer does not cover "powered" I love the picture.

Comment: That plane somehow reminds me of the Flintstones' cars...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It has in fact a motor, which is not used in this picture. I recommend taking a look at the manufactureres website =)

Comment: Can you find an image of it configured with a motor?

Comment: The preview image of the video shows one. It doesn't look that much different, I just has a folding prop sticking out of the back, also e.g. here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bb/Archaeopteryx_electric_motor.jpg

Comment: The first picture looks like someone's very elaborate Halloween costume.

Answer (score 12):

You should check out planes with custer wings.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Custer_CCW-5

It was claimed that the aircraft could fly under control at 11 mph (18 km/h) and that it could take off with a 1,500 lb (680 kg) load at 70% power in 90 ft (28 m).

Comment: Welcome. Interesting addition that should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Seems pretty answery to me, @mins. Addresses all the items in the OP: Powered. Fixed wing. Sustained flight at very slow air(?) speed. Has a link for more info, but provides the necessary facts in case Wikipedia ever dies...;)

Comment: @FreeMan: The question is about existing airplanes.

Comment: @mins: The question isn't very explicit about that.  It does use the present tense, but seems to leave the door open for interesting answers about past planes as long as they really flew, and weren't just designs on paper.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Even if it's not used anymore in civil or military aviation, the concept of channel wings is still used for modelism or prototypes (Handiwork 181, in 90s).

Comment: Feels like this plane has (at least) two relevant airspeeds. The 11 mph is likely not the airspeed inside the channels?

Answer (score 7):

### Slepcev Storch

(A 3/4-size replica of the [Fieseler Fi 156 Storch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fieseler_Fi_156), a German WW2 reconnaissance aircraft well known for its slow-speed performance)

**36 km/h or 40 km/h** (19kn/22kn)

[image]

<sup>[Picture Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Slepcev_Storch_HB-YKQ_OTT_2013_02.jpg)</sup>

> Performance according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slepcev_Storch):
>
> - Maximum speed: 150 km/h (93 mph; 81 kn)
> - Cruise speed: 133 km/h (83 mph; 72 kn)
> - Stall speed: 40 km/h (25 mph; 22 kn)
> - Rate of climb: 6 m/s (1,200 ft/min)

> Performance according to [ulm.it](http://www.ulm.it/fly_in/test/slepcev/default_en.htm):
>
> - Maximum speed: 150 km/h
> - VNE: 182 km/h
> - Stall speed: (flaps out) 36 Km/h
> - Climb rate: 9,1 m/s (1800 ft/min)

Comment: If the question involves non experimental fixed wing aircraft that were actually in general use, the Storch would have been the one I would think of.

Answer (score 2):

I was at the [Biggen Hill airshow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biggin_Hill_International_Air_Fair) many years ago where not one but two different aircraft flew backwards. One was the [AN-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-2) which was able to nose up into the headwind so far that it actually flew backwards for a short distance down the runway. The other was a Russian super jet, (possibly a [Sukhoi 27](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Su-27) or [Sukhoi 35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Su-35)?) that did a vertical climb on afterburners that shock the ground then slowed to a stop before falling on its tail while still vertical. It flew tail first towards the ground before lowering the nose.

Comment: That manoeuver is called [Pugachev's Cobra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pugachev%27s_Cobra).

Comment: @el.pescado Thank you. That was the stunt he flew that left me stunned. As you can imagine, there was no way to hear what the commentator had to say.

Answer (score 1):

Alaskan Bush Planes are modified to fly very slowly for short landings:

Features include:
"Short runway requirements, typically gained through high aspect ratio wings and high-lift devices such as flaps, slots and slats to improve low speed flight characteristics, allowing shorter ground rolls on landing or takeoff."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_plane

This might be helpful too:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_STOL_aircraft

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfD5epGswRw) is a video showing that the Gossamer Albatross flew at lowest speed, 7mph (11.2kmph). Very slow. But the save speed will be 10mph (16.1kmph), as mentioned in that video. It lasted 2 hours to cross England strait from England to France.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Review of Human Powered Flight to 1990](https://www.humanpoweredflight.co.uk/hpfMedia/media/7/Review-of-HPF-to-1990.pdf) (PDF) by Chris Roper, the [MIT Chrysalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_Chrysalis) human-powered aircraft "was in fact the slowest aircraft ever to fly," at 8mph.  The document covers other human-powered aircraft mentioned in other answers, including the Gossamer Condor and Albatross, so that suggests that the MIT Chrysalis was, in fact, the slowest fixed-wing manned aircraft to fly successfully.

Answer (score -1):

It is the shock ultra by savage.  Stalls at 18 mph.    2016 savage produced it and it by far out flies all other planes by a mile in the low and slow cathegory

Comment: Fairly sure a stall speed of 18mph doesn't beat the An-2's lack of a stall speed.

Comment: @Jules, this is a myth. First, An-2 does stall; it just remains somewhat controllable and very stable. This mode is called 'parachuting'; An-2 can 'parachute', fully stalled, to the ground and survive. Second, An-2 can _sustain_ flight at 40 km/h (~21 kt) the lowest (more practically 50-70 km/h, depending on the age and configuration). At anything slower it will descend.